# Total variation of a function on an interval $[0,2]$

Tags: real-analysis

If $f(x)=\sin x$ then what is the total variation of $f(x)$ on $[0,2]$?

Comment: answer will be 3 but how?

Comment: Split the domain into intervals on which $f$ is monotone.

Comment: But $2<2\pi$ so variation isn't automatically 2.

Comment: the sub intervals will be 0<pi/2, pi/2<2......?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For differentiable functions we have.(Thanks to user:Jakobian, we have to add the condition that function is Riemann Integrable)

$$\text{Var}_{[a,b]}(f) = \int_a^b |f'(x)| \, dx,$$

Comment: Already done using this formula..but don't get 3

Comment: For differentiable functions, that are Riemann integrable. It's important to include that they are Riemann integrable

Comment: yes....but the answer will be 2....Is it correct?

Comment: @Jakobian Thanks. I have edited the post

Comment: You don't get $3$ since that's not the answer. Likewise, you don't get $2$. @Tanmoyghosh

Comment: Then what is the answer?

Comment: @Tanmoyghosh $a=0 $ and $b=2$. Take $c=\pi/2 $ and then $\int |f'|=\int_{a}^{c}+\int_{c}^{b}$

Comment: @Tanmoyghosh Answer would be 1+1-sin(2)

Comment: Yes got it.....Thanx

Comment: Thanx a lot....

Comment: But it is showing that the answer is 2

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is monotone on $[a,b]$, then
its total variation on $[a,b]$ is $|f(a)-f(b)|$.
If $a<c<b$, the total variation of $f$ on $[a,b]$ is the sum of the total
variation of $f$ on $[a,c]$ and the total variation of $f$ on $[c,b]$.

Now, $\sin x$ is increasing on $[0,\pi/2]$ and decreasing on $[\pi/2,2]$, etc.